# Where are the Xcode debug files on Mojave?

Tags: xcode

Where are the Xcode debug files for my project located on my Mac running Mojave?

Comment: Update your question with what you mean by "debug files" if you want anyone to be able to answer your question.

Comment: Where is the project compiled to in the file system of Mojave?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode projects are compiled to its derived data location. You can find the derived data location in Xcode's Location Preferences. The default derived data location is the following:

```
/Users/YourUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

If you are trying to find the app you built, it's easier to select the app from the Products folder in the project navigator, right-click, and choose Show in Finder. You can find more detailed information in the following article:

[Changing Xcode’s Build Location](https://meandmark.com/blog/2015/08/changing-xcodes-build-location/)